# Change old files with new one on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

So my problem is that i don't know how to update a simple txt file. So what i have is that my app always read something from one file. Than i want to update this file with some stuf i bring down from internet. So what i can do is this:

```
    NSString *index2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"something.txt"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url to file"];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [urlData writeToFile:index2 atomically:YES];
```

So i downloaded the updated file and saved it to phone memory in documents Directory. But what i don't understand is how to overwrite a file for example index1 which i have in my bundle resources.

Thanks for the replieys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to overwrite the file that is in your bundle. What you should do is when the app starts:

1. Check if your file is in the Documents/ (or Library/ depending on your preference) folder
2. If it's not there, then make a copy using the one from your bundle
3. Then run your update and if needed, overwrite the copy you just put in Documents/

The idea is that your bundle never changes but your app relies on the copy that you made in Documents/ so that's the one you have to keep up to date.

Comment: ok thank u! i will try this and it sounds ok, i was just wondering about the other way...

Comment: BTw do u ahve any idea how to copy many files as fast as possible?

Comment: You might put a zip inside your bundle, copy the zip when the app first launches and then unzip it. It'll go much faster if you have lots of files.